# ggplot: adding new lines from a subset of years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have about 90 years of daily data and I want to plot the long term mean, plus the individual lines for each year of my survey period (2014-2018). The data looks like this:

```
> head(dischg)
      date   ddmm year cfs      daymo
1 1-Jan-27 01-Jan 1927 715 2018-01-01
2 2-Jan-27 02-Jan 1927 697 2018-01-02
3 3-Jan-27 03-Jan 1927 715 2018-01-03
4 4-Jan-27 04-Jan 1927 796 2018-01-04
5 5-Jan-27 05-Jan 1927 825 2018-01-05
6 6-Jan-27 06-Jan 1927 865 2018-01-06
```

I have been able to plot the long term mean easily enough:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dischg, aes(x=daymo, y=cfs)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "smooth", colour = "blue")
```

... but I need some help plotting the subset of years. I tried using "subset"

```
p2 <- p1 +
  ggplot (subset(dischg, year %in% c(2014:2018)), aes(x=daymo, y=cfs, linetype=year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

but I received this error:

> Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

Would it be smarter to just add one year at a time? That seems a bit cumbersome when there are five years of data to plot.

Comment: You can't add `ggplot` to a `ggplot` object already. Try removing the second `ggplot` call and doing: `geom_line(subset(dischg, year %in% c(2014:2018)), aes( linetype=year))`. I also removed the repeated `aes()` for `x` and `y` because they will be inherited. I unfortunately cannot create the plot with the data because there are too few observations

Comment: @MikeH. consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks! I tried this: `p2 <- p1 +
  geom_line(subset(dischg, year %in% c(2014:2018)), 
   aes(linetype=year)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") ` but received an error: `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`. Help?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik good call. Put my comment with a little more explanation as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing sample data, however, I unfortunately cannot get the `ggplot` code to run with that sample data you provided so I will use a built in R dataset. The concepts are the same though.

The issue is that you are trying to add `ggplot` to an object that is already of class `ggplot`. Once you have initialized your object as a `ggplot` object, you don't need to call `ggplot` each time you want to add a layer. For example, I get the same error you do if I try:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,y=cyl)) + geom_point()
p2 <- p1 + ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ], aes(x = hp, y = cyl)) + geom_line()
```

As mentioned in my comment, if you want to add another layer with separate data (in your case the `geom_line`) you can do this by putting the data directly into the `geom_` call. In your case you would do something like:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,y=cyl)) + geom_point()
p2 <- p1 + geom_line(data = mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ])

p2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to feedback from @MikeH., I figured it out:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dischg, aes(x=daymo, y=cfs)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "smooth", colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(data=subset(dischg, year %in% c(2014:2018)), 
            aes(colour=year)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

(Also, I had to make sure the 'year' was a factor rather than a continuous variable.)