# Ggplot and sf for overlaying two layers of polygons (.shp)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have two polygon '.shp' files. I need one to appear on the map by filling in one variable and the other to appear only on borders, overlapping the first.

I have already used 'ggplot2' and 'sf'.

I plotted a map ('map1'), which is layered with polygons, using 'ggplot' and 'geom_sf'.

I use a variable ('var1') contained in 'map1' as a 'fill'.

Now, I need to add (overlay) another layer of polygons on top ('map2'). This will have to be 'transparent fill' or 'no fill'. Only appearing the outline of the borders.

```
library(ggplot2); library(sf)

map1 <- st_read("m1.shp") #reading polygon layer map 1

map2 <- st_read("m2.shp")#reading polygon layer map 2 

g <- ggplot(map1, aes(fill = var1)) + 
    geom_sf()
```

How can i add 'map2' for overlay this map?

The idea would be:

```
g <- ggplot(map1, aes(fill = var1)) + 
    geom_sf() +
ggplot(map2, aes()) + 
    geom_sf() 

#Error: Don't know how to add ggplot(map2, aes()) to a plot
```

Comment: You can add layers to a ggplot (not just sf related ones) like `ggplot(data) + geom_line() + geom_point()`. You only call `ggplot` once, but then can add multiple layers on top of the object that creates. If you need data specific to one layer, use the `data` argument in your geom

Comment: About the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50121712/5325862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every geom_SOMETHING() function has a **data** argument where you can configure the data you are using. This argument plays the same role as the **data** argument in the ggplot() function. When you specify **data** in ggplot, all the other geom_SOMETHING() function inherit the argument. The same happens with the arguments in **aes()**

So the first recommendation is remove the **data = map1** and **aes** arguments from ggplot and add it to the geom_sf function.

```
g <- ggplot() + geom_sf(map1, aes(fill = var1)) + geom_sf(map2)
```

Comment: Also, chek [this tutorial](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html)

Comment: This worked when I added **data =**. `g <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = map1, aes(fill = var1)) + geom_sf(data = map2)`. 
Without the **data =** argument, this error arises: **Error: 'mapping' must be created by 'aes()'.** Thanks!

Comment: For transparent fill on the overlay map:
`ggplot() + geom_sf(data = map1, aes(fill = var1)) + geom_sf(data = map2, alpha = 0)`

Comment: @Patricia I've been trying for about 3 hours to figure out how to get around this problem and your tip to ad 'data = ' has solved it - THANK YOU SO MUCH!