# ggplot sf variable factor with specific point colour, and size, with sf geometry

Tags: ggplot2, r-sf

i have a [shp file](https://%20https://data.imas.utas.edu.au/attachments/275f62b0-0b6c-4514-90c7-deeae423ab23/MarineFutures_GeographeBay_reef.zip) , with lat lon
( `shp_4283 <- sf::st_transform(shp, crs = 4283)` )
and 3 variables, of which i would like to plot the separate
`$Substrate` factors to separate colours and to their `$geometry` locations.

with geom_sf..

```
    ggplot() +
  
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Sand", show.legend = "point"), #aes(shape = YOU), 
              color = "yellow", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Mixed reef and sand", show.legend = "point"), #aes(shape = YOU),
             color = "green", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "None modelled with certainty", show.legend = "point"), #aes(shape = YOU),
             color = "grey", size = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Reef", show.legend = "point"), #aes(shape = YOU),
             color = "black", size = 2, show.legend = T) +
    coord_sf()
```

the plot works, but with no legend as no `aes()` set.. but then further errors occur due to "Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list'"

I understand to create a new `df` filtering each factor and its geometry to then plot from..

```
df <- shp_4283 %>%
  # Your filter
  filter(Substrate == "Reef") %>%
  # 2 Extract coordinates
  st_coordinates() %>%
  # 3 to table /tibble
  as.data.frame() %>% 
**is this where i would code the 'column names' so that each 
filtered $Substrate factor in a new df would be labelled appropriately?**
```

but is there a `geom_..` way to plot separate variable factor from the sf df with its geometry.. and the legend mapping the color to the factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**geom_sf()** & **subset()** & explicit **layer call**
to view the smallest data-group last, on top of the progressively larger data-groups beneath

```
Col = c('green','grey','black','yellow') #define data-group colours


jr_map <-  ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = shp_4283, aes(color = Substrate)) + # to map all data-groups to the plot, and more importantly, the legend.. legend appears now.. but not correct color-mapping
# individually map the separate groups, by factor, add point size, and legend visibility
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Sand", show.legend = "point"), color = "yellow", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Mixed reef and sand", show.legend = "point"), color = "green", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "None modelled with certainty", show.legend = "point"), color = "grey", size = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = subset(shp_4283, Substrate == "Reef", show.legend = "point"), color = "black", size = 2) +
# retrieve geometry 
  coord_sf() +
# add label for map projection/CRS
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 115.095:115.1, y = -33.62:-33.6, label = "crs = 4283", 
           fontface = "italic", color = "grey22", size = 2.5) + 
  #geom_text(data=bb_df, aes(x=115,y=35), fill='black', color='black', alpha=.1, angle=35) + # incase an on-map descriptive label needed
# add north arrow
annotation_north_arrow(location = "bl", which_north = "true", 
                         pad_x = unit(0.25, "cm"), 
                         pad_y = unit(0.25, "cm"),
                         height = unit(0.6, "cm"), width = unit(0.6, "cm"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) +
  theme_bw() + # remove 'azure' ocean color
  ggtitle("Jolly-Rog Drops" , subtitle = "Geographe Bay, Western Australia") +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  ## Legend : CUSTOM
  #Title, colors (Col specified manually at start..ordered according to $Substrate listing), 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Substrate", values = Col) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(2,2,2,2), size = 1, fill = Col), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, legend.text = element_text(size=0.2)) ) + # size and shape NOT WORKING!? HELP..
  #theme(legend.position = c(0, 0))                                 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

jr_map
```

also thanks to this post ([geom_ explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018950/ggplot-and-sf-for-overlaying-two-layers-of-polygons-shp?rq=1))

the different variable factors (`$Substrate`) are 1. geo-plotted, and their 2. respective visibility, is easily adjustable, dependent on the **layer** at which they are coded from initial `ggplot()` call (farthest/last most prominent). The `geom_sf()` points (not `geom_point()`) are then made prominent through **colour**, **shape**, and **size** of point (`alpha =`  also available).